# Check if 2 array elements are equal and print yes if so, and no if it isn't for each check

Tags: c#, arrays, string, element, equality

I want to check if 2 string elements in array are equal and print Yes if so, and no if the new string isn't inserted to array before. The problem is that I want if I inserted 6 elements, I want to print 6 Yes or No, but the number of Yes and No is not equal to the number of elements inserted.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string[] names = new string[num];

        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            names[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < names.Length; j++)
            {
                if (names[i] == names[j])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("No");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're printing a line of output for every combination, e.g. element 0 against each of elements 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... then element 1 against each of elements 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. Did you actually just want to print "No" if *no* other element in the array is equal to the element you're checking?

Comment: What is your primary goal: just to print __for each element__ of the array if it __has duplicates?__ Thus for 6 _names_ there would be 6 _lines_ printed, each with either `Yes` or `No` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want "for each item in the list print yes/no if the item shows up more than once in the list":

```
 Console.Write(String.Join(",",
        names.Select(n => names.Count(x => x == n) > 1 ? "yes" : "no")));
```

The core part is to `.Count` how many times given string happens in the array.